# 2 javascripts plugin not working together

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to implement 2 plugins in a page and when i introduce the 2nd one... the 1st plugins stops working .. can you please help me in this.. he is the page i am trying to build..

http://www.abc.com/home21

and here are the 2 plugins i am trying to use.

http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/how-to-integrate-a-slideshow-in-your-wordpress-theme

http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/

here is my code.. The rating script was working from beginning. i tried to add this slideshow in this page like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="testing/t1/css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="testing/t1/css/jd.gallery.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
<script src="testing/t1/scripts/mootools.v1.11.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="testing/t1/scripts/jd.gallery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="testing/t1/scripts/jd.gallery.transitions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var newj = jQuery.noConflict();
function startGallery() {
var myGallery = new gallery(newj('myGallery'), {
timed: true,
showArrows: false,
embedLinks: false,
showCarousel: true,
defaultTransition: "continuoushorizontal"
});
   }  window.onDomReady(startGallery);

  </script>
```

please help me how to solve this problem

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of jQuery.  If I had a dollar for ever bug or conflict I found with a plugin...

Comment: The solution Woppi suggests will work for you.  My advice, however, would be to use a jQuery slideshow or a Mootools star rating system, and don't try to use two different libraries on the same page.  Apart from anything else, this will cause higher loading times, but it will also cause all kinds of headaches like this one.

Comment: Hmmm...try this jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: then use "jQuery" as an alias for your star rating. I snatch from docu...sample rating plugin...                                                    jQuery('.auto-submit-star').rating({
callback: function(value, link){
alert(value);
}
});

Comment: @Woppi - please have a look at code now....since i added slideshow later.. i di it for slidewhow

Comment: This gallery is mootools, yes? The alias is for jQuery, the star rating. You can use $ for the gallery. No need to rename the gallery. I had the same case before and this solution worked for me.

Comment: @Woppi  - but i am already using $ all over my site....so is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using both Mootools and JQuery. These two javascript libraries overwrite each other.

http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/how-to-integrate-a-slideshow-in-your-wordpress-theme uses Mootools
http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/ uses Jquery

You will need to find plugins that only use jquery or mootools. See:

http://mootools.net/forge/

http://plugins.jquery.com/

For more plugins for each framework.

Answer (score 2):

So the first one is MooTools, the second is jQuery. You can try to do $.noConflict()

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

```
jQuery.noConflict();
function startGallery() {
var myGallery = new gallery($('myGallery'), {
timed: true,
showArrows: false,
embedLinks: false,
showCarousel: true,
defaultTransition: "continuoushorizontal"
});
}  window.onDomReady(startGallery);
```

Regarding your using of $ all over your site, this would do it(based on docu):

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script><!-- your mootools lib-->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $.noConflict();
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
 $('#id-here').click(function(e) {
     alert('I can use $ here with no conflicts on other js libraries!');
 });

 });
 // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
     function startGallery() {
     var myGallery = new gallery($('myGallery'), {
     timed: true,
     showArrows: false,
     embedLinks: false,
     showCarousel: true,
     defaultTransition: "continuoushorizontal"
    });
  }  window.onDomReady(startGallery);
 </script>
```

If this still didn't work, take time to read the manual...you will get it eventually^^ Just know using .noConflict worked for me on a similar case I had a while back.

Though I'm curious where your star rating code is located...

Comment: Never seen that before, quite impressed. Correct me if I am wrong but would you need to re-reference all the $() functions in the jquery code?

Comment: In the documentation, there are a lot of ways of doing it. You can try and see what fits your coding. I've tried playing with it a long time ago...you can do this                                        var ian = jQuery.noConflict();

ian('#id-here').live('click', function(e) { //code here });

Comment: Now that you've done that other library can use $...haha! Have fun!

Comment: @Woppi - i gets js error like $ is not a function. i did the same way u showed in code.

Comment: Kinda hard to debug when I don't see the entire code dude...what I showed you is how to use .noConflict, the way you implement would be based on how you structure your code